# Oracle SQL Pivot Command Not Working -- "Invalid Idenitifier"

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I am trying to do a simple query in Oracle SQL using Pivot. I have 12 columns in my table, but only the first four are of interest. The columns are "FACILITY_ID" (Unique Identifier), "REPORTING_YEAR" (Year data was reported), "SUBPART" (Category of data wanting to pivot by - values acceptable between A and Z), and "CO2E" (floating point number reported). I want to take only the data from subparts C and K (the third column) and add them up into their own columns.

For example:
If my original table looks like:

```
FACILITY_ID --- REPORTING_YEAR --- SUBPART --- CO2E  
10    -------------- 2020 ---------------------- C  -------- 10  
11    -------------- 2020 ---------------------- K  -------- 20  
10    -------------- 2020 ---------------------- K  -------- 40  
10    -------------- 2020 ---------------------- K  -------- 40  
11    -------------- 2020 ---------------------- C  -------- 30
```

I would like to get something like:

```
FACILITY_ID --- REPORTING_YEAR ----- C ----- K    
10    -------------- 2020 ----------------- 10  ----- 80  
11    -------------- 2020 ----------------- 30  ----- 20
```

My code as of now is as follows:

```
Create Table CandK_emissions as
  Select
    FACILITY_ID,
    REPORTING_YEAR,
    SUBPART,
    CO2E
  From
    facilityReport
  Pivot
  (
     Sum(CO2E)
     For SUBPART
     in ('C',
     'K')
  )
```

The error I'm getting is 'Ora-00904: "CO2e": Invalid Identifier'. I've double checked that everything is spelled correctly. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Removed, thank you @jarlh

Comment: Something is wrong. In other places you show either CO2E (not in double-quotes, so capitalization doesn't matter) or "CO2E" in all-caps and in double-quotes (making the name case sensitive). But the error message complains about "CO2e" with a lower-case "e", That could be the problem - but you said "you checked that everything is spelled correctly." I don't think Oracle changes E to e on its own, even for showing it in an error message. Perhaps you didn't check carefully enough?

Comment: After you get past that problem, you may find that your query actually doesn't work. PIVOT assumes that the data must be grouped by all the columns not referenced in the PIVOT clause; so if you must ignore some other columns for the purpose of "grouping", you shouldn't select (and then pivot) from your entire table, but from an inline subquery where you only select the relevant columns form the base table.

Comment: @mathguy you can ignore the capitalization. It is all capitalized in my actual Oracle. I just retyped and slightly changed the names because I wasn't able to copy and paste it over for VDI reasons. I'll try either first selecting the four columns and making a table or changing my query. I'm very new to all this

Comment: OK, sorry - I see the issue now. In your current query (whether it will end up doing what you need or not), you pivot SUM(CO2E) for (....). After pivoting, there is no CO2E column in the result; the sum of CO2E will appear either in column C or in column K. So, what is CO2E doing in the SELECT clause? That's what is causing that error. Same with SUBPART. What you should select instead are C and K. The SELECT clause should show the columns that will appear in your output (not the columns that exist in the input table).

Comment: @mathguy Yes, I was able to get it with your second comment. It turns out I just had to make sure I was pivoting only from a query which only contained those four columns.

Answer (score 0):

The `SELECT` clause must show what columns will exist in the output, not what columns are used from the base table. In your query, you are aggregating the CO2E values, separately for different values of SUBPART. The result of pivoting doesn't have CO2E values anymore, or SUBPART values; instead, the two SUBPART values you are interested in, C and K, become two distinct columns in the output, and the sums of CO2E appear in these two new columns.

Your query should SELECT columns C and K; the error message is telling you that after pivoting, there is no CO2E column to select. (After you change that, it would tell you the same thing about SUBPART.)

Here is how this should look. Note a few things: In the "test data" I simulated one more column, a primary key named PK, to demonstrate that you must EXCLUDE it first, in an inline view (the sub-SELECT in the FROM clause). Also note that, to make the PIVOT as efficient as possible, in the subquery I only select the rows we need - those where the SUBPART is either C or K. We don't need to see the other rows.

The WITH clause is just for testing - remove it, and use your actual table and column names in the query.

```
with
  test_data (pk, facility_id, reporting_year, subpart, co2e) as (
    select 335, 10, 2020, 'C', 10 from dual union all
    select 440, 11, 2020, 'K', 20 from dual union all
    select 482, 10, 2020, 'K', 40 from dual union all
    select 106, 10, 2020, 'K', 40 from dual union all
    select 476, 11, 2020, 'C', 30 from dual
  )
-- end of test data; actual query begins below this line
select facility_id, reporting_year, c, k
from   (
         select facility_id, reporting_year, subpart, co2e
         from   test_data
         where  subpart in ('C', 'K')
       )
pivot  (sum(co2e) for subpart in ('C' as c, 'K' as k))
order  by facility_id, reporting_year  --  or whatever is needed
;

FACILITY_ID REPORTING_YEAR          C          K
----------- -------------- ---------- ----------
         10           2020         10         80
         11           2020         30         20
```

Note - it may be simpler (and more efficient) to do away with PIVOT altogether, and to "pivot" the old way, using conditional aggregation (the way pivoting was done before the PIVOT operator was introduced). Something like this:

```
select facility_id, reporting_year,
       sum(case subpart when 'C' then co2e end) as c,
       sum(case subpart when 'K' then co2e end) as k
from   test_data
group  by facility_id, reporting_year
order  by facility_id, reporting_year
;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this. This is good to know moving forward - I like the simpler method without pivot. I'll try to run with that in the future